# Cannot forward/nat traffic to vboxnet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat

We have a guest vagrant/virtualbox machine (ip 192.168.50.10) inside a host (ip 192.168.50.1 and two interfaces, the second one with public ip 104.x.x.x).

On the host, we want to forward traffic from 104.x.x.x to the guest. To get a clear ip tables rules, these are the commands we ran:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -d 104.x.x.x -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.50.10
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.50.10 -j SNAT --to-source 104.x.x.x
```

But sadly it doesn't work, and even `tcpdump -i vboxnet1 -vv -n` shows no packet being passed to vboxnet1 interface.

net.ipv4.ip_forward is set to 1, and the guest machine is accessible through 192.168.50.10 on the host.

Anything that could help? Thanks.